# error when changing mount location for external hdd

Tags: linux, mount-point

I will admit this might be a bit complicated and maybe not the best method so if you have a better solution let me know...

I have a 'server' that I put lubuntu 14.4 on. I am attempting to attach an external hdd formatted to ext3 to the folder /home/external so that my ftp users are able to get to the files on it without leaving the /home directory (to which I have them 'chained' / chrooted).

The hdd will mount just fine (no errors) with the automatic mount options. but every time I try to change the mount point to something other than /media//external I get:

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdd1: Command-line `mount "/mnt/
external"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, 
bad superblock on /dev/sdd1
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
   (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

As far as I can tell it does not matter where I try to mount it even tried /mnt/external with same results.

Output of dmesg | tail (before mount changes):

```
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
sdd: sdd1
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
EXT4-fs (sdd1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
EXT4-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Output of dmesg | tail (after mount changes):

```
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
sdd: sdd1
sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
EXT4-fs (sdd1): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
EXT4-fs (sdd1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
EXT4-fs (sdd1): Unrecognized mount option "x-gvfs-show" or missing value
```

Comment: This might be better posted at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Should I remove this one then post the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed: I was using the disks GUI to change the mount options because I didn't want to screw up my fstab.conf file. For some reason when I check 'Show in user interface' it only adds x-gvfs-show instad of comment=x-gvfs-show (which is apparently the correct syntax for that option). Having manually added the 'comment=' I can say the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, did you actually unmount the block device in question before you tried to mount it on a different location?

Comment: Yes, I unmounted via the 'eject' button in the disks utility

Comment: @mike This should be a comment not an answer

Comment: @mathematician1975 - sorry, my bad. :) C0deGyver have you looked at kernel logs as suggested by mount stderr?. also, what filesystem is installed on that device? Maybe you should load proper fs module into the kernel (if not compiled directly in the code) before you manually change the mount point (and after you use that 'eject' button).

Comment: How do you mount the device? Do you define any additional options? How your fstab conf file looks like?  also, df -hT, grep -i sdd1 /proc/mounts would be handy (before changing the mount points).